# Leafletjs the map does not move inside it

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to make the map move inside it, dragging the map to the side, so I can get around the map.

But this is only being possible `onmousedown` on `map1`, when choosing `map2` the map does not move, it is not possible to drag it.

When clicking on the `map1 button` the map appears and it is possible to move within it, but after I click on the `map2 button` it is no longer possible to move within the map.

Follow the code of what is happening.

How could this be fixed?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin: 10px">
        <button onclick="maps(['New York', 40.6971494, -74.2598757])">Map 1</button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 10px">
        <button onclick="maps(['London', 51.528308, -0.3817849])">Map 2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 10px"></div>

    <script>
        function maps(location) {
            var container = L.DomUtil.get('mapid');
            if(container != null){
                container._leaflet_id = null;
            }

            var map = L.map( 'mapid', {
                center: [location[1], location[2]],
                minZoom: 2,
                zoom: 13
              });
            
            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

            var m = L.marker([location[1], location[2]]).addTo(map).bindPopup(location[0])

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, I needed to change the way the map was initialized, follow the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin: 10px">
        <button onclick="maps(['New York', 40.6971494, -74.2598757])">Map 1</button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 10px">
        <button onclick="maps(['London', 51.528308, -0.3817849])">Map 2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 10px"></div>

    <script>
        var map = null; //added

        function maps(location) {
            
            //var container = L.DomUtil.get('mapid'); //removed
            //if(container != null){                  //removed
            //    container._leaflet_id = null;       //removed
            //}

            if (map !== undefined && map !== null) { map.remove(); }//added

            map = L.map( 'mapid', { //alterated
                center: [location[1], location[2]],
                minZoom: 2,
                zoom: 13
              });
            
            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

            var m = L.marker([location[1], location[2]]).addTo(map).bindPopup(location[0])

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```